# How to access unmounted network drive files on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, network-drive

I have a remote host called `myhost` and I have some log files that I want to access in the terminal.

For example, I can access this in my browser:

```
file://myhost/f$/logs/dev.log
```

But when I try this in the terminal

```
scp -p "username@myhost:/f$/logs/dev.log" "/home/Documents"
```

it gives me the 'cannot stat' error:

```
cp: cannot stat `username@myhost:/f$/logs/dev.log': No such file or directory
```

I have tried using `username@file://myhost` and `username@//myhost` but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were exactly is the file stored on your remote host (from /)?  Just because it's in myhost/f$/logs/dev.log in your browser does not mean it's in the same spot relative to user-login.  Second question is, can you ssh in fine?

Comment: Your error message says `\`username@myhost:/f$/logs/dev.lo'` (note missing `g` at the end). Is that a typo in the error message or the cause of your problem?

Comment: The remote host is another machine shared within the network. And yes I can ssh into the machine using the same username but it is strongly not recommended. So maybe that's the problem here?

Comment: @Dennis, good eyes! But that's just a typo. Thanks!

Comment: When you logon with ssh, is it in `/f$/logs/dev.log` or is it in `/_<homedir>_/f$/logs/dev.log`?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe it is in `/f$/logs/dev.log`. Solve the problem using `wget`, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clarify the solution using wget:

Since I can use the URL to access the file, I simply use this line in my batch:

```
wget -q //myhost/f$/logs/dev.log -Y off
```

where "-q" means:

> Turn on verbose output, with all the available data. The default
>   output is verbose.

and "-Y" means:

> Turn proxy on or off

This will download the file in the current directories and it solves my problem.

Reference:
http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html